# How to get JQuery, AJAX and JSON to show/hide form button while displaying an alert at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am having a little problem to get the button selector "#view_btn" to show 
whenever the return "data.res" result var contains a successful message.

The scripts works, but the "#view_btn" selector will not show at all when there is an 
success.

If I replace the "data.res" with "data" in the if statements, then the button will
always showing even when it should be hiding.

What is it the I am doing that's wrong?  Can someone please help?  Thanks.

```
// This is the PHP script: hello.php
 <?php

    // some code goes here:

    if(isset($error)) 
    {
         echo json_encode(array("res"=>'error',"msg"=>$error));
    }
    else if (isset($success))
    {
         echo json_encode(array("res"=>'success',"msg"=>$success));
    }
    else 
    {
         echo json_encode(array("res"=>'message',"msg"=>$message));
    }

?>
```

This is the JQuery in the index.php HTML header.

```
</script>

   $(function() {
       $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
       var pid  = $('#prod').attr("dir");
       var base_url = "<?php echo $base_URL; ?>/my_ajax/"+ pid +"/hello.php";
       $('#loading').show('fast');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: base_url,
          data: $("#pdForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
          cache: false,
          dataType:"json"
       }).done(function( data ) {
       $('#loading').hide('fast');
          if(data.res == 'success' ){
              $('#view_btn').show(); // show the button
              alert(data.msg); // show response from the php script.
          }else if (data.res == 'error') {
              $('#view_btn').hide();    // hide the button
              alert(data.msg); // show response from the php script.
          }else if (data.res == 'message') {
              $('#view_btn').hide();    // hide the button
              alert(data.msg); // show response from the php script.
          }else {
              $('#view_btn').hide();    // hide the button
              alert('Query data failed or invalid!'); // show response.
          }
       }, "json");
       return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
      });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: What `console.log(data)` shows in your `done`-function?

Comment: The <code>console.log(data)</code> is empty.

Comment: The problem maybe that <code>.done()</code> has only one callback and it is the success callback

Comment: If your php-script runs without errors and returning normal values - then `done` callback will work. You can also add `fail` callback and alert some messages in both `done` and `fail` callbacks so as to see which callback works. But if you can see `console.log` in `done` callback - it clearly works. Maybe there's some error in html element naming - wrong ID or class instead ID?

Comment: Problem solved by replacing the following piece of code in the JQuery if statement by replacing the "data.res == 'success'with "data && data.res == 'success'".